# Нужна ли запятая в сочетании "а (,) как известно"

Tags: пунктуация

> *На протяжении нескольких дней центральные телевизионные каналы практически игнорировали протесты в Ереване, а, как известно, чего не
>   показывают по телевизору, того... не существует.*

Нужна ли запятая после союза "а"?

Answer (score 4):

На протяжении нескольких дней центральные телевизионные каналы практически игнорировали протесты в Ереване, **а, как известно, чего не показывают** по телевизору, того... не существует.

Вводное слово *как известно* можно переставить или убрать, поэтому оно обособляется.

А – это сочинительный союз, который выражает отношение между частями сложного предложения, то есть **относится к структуре** этого предложения. Вводное слово с ним не связано.

Comment: На протяжении нескольких дней центральные телевизионные каналы практически игнорировали протесты в Ереване, а чего не показывают по телевизору, того... не существует.

Comment: Так грамотно сказать ?

Comment: А почему Вам это кажется неграмотным? По крайней мере, вводное слово принципиально ничего не меняет.

Comment: Думаю, что цитата взята вот отсюда: http://провэд.рф/article/47487-chto-proizoshlo-v-armenii-.html (в тексте после "а" запятая отсутствует). А очень хочется ее там иметь, я солидарна с Вами  (свой ответ давать не вижу смысла).

Answer (score 1):

**На протяжении нескольких дней центральные телевизионные каналы практически игнорировали протесты в Ереване, а, как известно, чего не показывают по телевизору, того... не существует.**

> Запятая после союза ставится, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры. ([3. Вводное слово и союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2))

Там же приведены примеры с союзом *а*, которые помогут всем понять, когда 
вводное слово можно опустить:

> Однако Володя, видя, как трудно мальчишке, совсем не ругался, **а, наоборот**, говорил нечто подбодряющее (Ю. Визбор,  Альтернатива вершины Ключ).

Вводное слово *наоборот* можно опустить.

> **А может быть**, с малайцем вы ушли (А. Вертинский, Где вы теперь).

Вводное слово *может быть* опустить нельзя.

> Трава на нашей поляне, пожелтевшая и сморенная, все же осталась живой и мягкой, на ней возились свободные от игры, **а лучше сказать**, проигравшиеся ребята (В. Распутин, Уроки французского).

Вводное слово *лучше сказать* опустить нельзя.

> Случайно появляется газ или нет, связан ли он с циклонами, **а значит**, можно ли по этому признаку прогнозировать – вопрос требует выяснения (А. Гладилин, Прогноз на завтра).

Вводное слово *значит* опустить нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Правило такого. Если  изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, то запятая после сочинительного союза не ставится (обычно при союзе а).

> **А впрочем,** беды большой нет, если до Рейна ничего не увидишь (Герц.).
>
> Мы знаем, **а стало быть,** верим, что сказкам сбываться дано (Мих.).

В вашем примере  изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, т.к. нарушается структура предложения.

Ср.: На протяжении нескольких дней центральные телевизионные каналы практически игнорировали протесты в Ереване, **а чего не показывают** по телевизору, того...  не существует.

**Поэтому запятая не ставится.**

На протяжении нескольких дней центральные телевизионные каналы практически игнорировали протесты в Ереване, **а как известно,** чего не показывают по телевизору, того... не существует.

Comment: Серж, по-моему, Вы запутались!  Разве при изъятии "как известно" структура рассматриваемого предложения нарушается?

Comment: А если не нарушается, то "как известно" в соответствии с приведённым Вами правилом нужно выделить запятыми. Запятая после "а" **нужна**.

Comment: Для них он герой, а, признаться сказать, я себе героев иначе представляю (Т.);Для них он герой, а я себе героев иначе представляю (Т.); Убрали вводное слово, структура не нарушилась. Союз а соединяет части сложного предложения.

Comment: – Расчёты были сделаны наскоро, а следовательно, и неточно (невозможно: Расчёты были сделаны наскоро, а и неточно);